# How to find out if a function belongs to $H^2$ or $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I'm beginning with Sobolev spaces and I found out, that

$$
H^k = W^{k,2}.
$$

I've also seen the following exercise recently:

$$
\frac{1}{2}u'' = 1
$$

And here I'm supposed to find out if $u$ belongs to $H^1, H^2$ etc.

---

Could you, please, explain it to me?

---

I know, that Sobolev space has a norm

$$
||u||_{k,p}  = \left( \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} \int_\Omega \left| D^\alpha u(x) \right|^p dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$

and that it's a complete space. But still, I'm not sure about a way, how to show, that some function belongs into it.

Comment: Unclear. What is the sense of the equation $u''=-2$? On what domain are you solving it? In most possible senses, your solution will be a quadratic function; hence it can be integrable only on bounded intervals, together with its derivatives.

Comment: Do you know about Du Bouis Raymond's Lemma and derivatives of distribution?

Comment: @Siminore I'm not sure now, I don't have the book with me - I can simply rewrite it without $-$, it's not the point for me now.

Comment: @BBVM I know about derivatives of distribution and I don't know the lemma.

Comment: Maybe you can write down a general formula for $u(x)$. Then determine if $\int_\Omega |u(x)|^2 dx < \infty$ or not, since that must be true if $u \in H^1$ or $u \in H^2$. You will find that this depends on the domain $\Omega$. After having understood this, give a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that for each $f \in L^{p}_{loc}(\Omega)$ we can define a Distribution  by:

$T_{f}: \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $T_{f}(\phi) = \displaystyle\int_{\Omega}f\phi$.

In the case, $T_{f}$ is called regular distribution.

The Du Bouis Reymond Lemma states that the map $f\mapsto T_{f}$ is one-to-one. However, there are Distributions which can't associated with $f \in L^{p}(\Omega)$ (Dirac's Distributions is a classic example).

Now consider the Heaviside's function, clearly this function belongs to $L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$, so can be associated with a distribution, but the derivative of this distribution can't be associated with a function in $L^{1}_{loc}(\Omega)$. So, a problem arises, because I would like (for some reason) that derivatives of regular distributions, was regular too. For this reason, the Sobolev spaces arises.

For exmaple, the space $W^{1,2}(\Omega) = H^{1}(\Omega) = \lbrace u\in L^{2}(\Omega); \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}} \in L^{2}(\Omega)\rbrace$.

The derivate in this definition, is the derivative of distribution associated to $u$.